# Client certificates in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

how to use client certificate authentication in wcf, if the client is using certificate for authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
```

in your service conf, to tell WCF that the crendential are provided by a client certificate.

and set the messageEncoding="Mtom"

```
<wsHttpBinding>
 <binding name="wshttpconfig" messageEncoding="Mtom">
           <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="64000" />
            <security mode="Transport">
             <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
           </security>
 </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

See this links

[An easy way to use certificates for WCF security](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcfcertificates.aspx)

[Configuring WCF for client certificate authentication](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/cfolini/archive/2008/01/04/90561.aspx)

[Using Certificate-based Authentication and Protection with Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://notgartner.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/using-certificate-based-authentication-and-protection-with-windows-communication-foundation-wcf/)

Bye.