# WCF Client 4.5 C# using CA certificate authority ssl cert. Need assistance, given up

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https

There are many asking somewhat the same question on here.  But very few answers, or reports of success.  The server is a third party so I do not know their configuration but they did report what they found in their logs the following:

The only thing they see in the log is this error.  "Based on the IP it is coming from their DEV environment, but there is no payload and for it to drop into the debug the URL is not formed correctly."

Node       : 
Time       : 20150105 10:21:45.798
Severity   : WARNING
Request Id : 00000149c32c8869-3801
Message    : Message processed successfully

Event Type : Message Summary
Client IP  : 56.6.66.6
Service    : Catch-all debug service [/*]
Operation  : null
Rqst Length: 0
Resp Length: 0
Resp Status: 0
Resp Time  : 0ms
User ID    : 
User Name  : null

Here is the full story,

I never had a problem calling a WebService that is on an https server.  But they have ip security as well as a certificate security (no username and password security)

Whats odd is they sent physical .wsdl files when usually I use visual studio, point to them and all is ready to go.  This is not the case.  I had to add the files locally, and point to them locally c:\project\Server References\file.wsdl  and everything did populate ok.

I have googled about 10 examples (all somewhat variant) on how to accomplish this.   Of course this can be done config less(all code) or everything defined in the config.  It can also be done in a console application or a web application.  For sanity purposes I prefer the console, but I have both going just encase.

P.S.  We hold the SSL cert and the authority as the client, and sent them the SSL cert without the private key.

P.S.S I have used Wireshark and Fiddler.  Wireshark shows the TCP connection on the 8443 port and the url in plain text, but the data portion seems to be too small to hold a certificate (but is this just the open call thats working properly?)

http://tinypic.com/r/34ihld4/8   (wireshark screen shot)

http://tinypic.com/r/14jrbx3/8  (wsclient in watch)

Fiddler showed a "successful handshake"

Here is the "config less code" that i am using

```
        ws.AccountInfo ai = new ws.AccountInfo();
        ws.BasicAccountInfo[] info = new ws.BasicAccountInfo[10];

        ws.ProductAndService PaS = new ws.ProductAndService();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 //have tried them all | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        WSHttpBinding myBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
        myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
        myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        myBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
        myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        myBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("https://www.some-company.com:8443/DSMProgramsV4/PgnDSMProgramsService");  //odly no .svc ending



        ws.PgnDSMProgramsServiceClient wsclient = new ws.PgnDSMProgramsServiceClient(myBinding,ea);


        // Specify a certificate to use for authenticating the client.
        wsclient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine,StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "Network Solutions DV Server CA");//the cert i want is found under this name for example www.somesite.com is found and shows up in watch in wsclient below

        string s = "";
        try
        {
            wsclient.Open();//success always
            info = wsclient.GetAccountList("9999", "TEST", "99999999");
            wsclient.Close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             s = ex.Message;// hang and error happens on GetAccount List
        }
        Console.Write(s);
        Console.Write(info[0].ToString());//if we were ever successful, never are though
```

There error i get is An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://www.some-company.com:8443/DSMProgramsV4/PgnDSMProgramsService. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

I can never get by this message

I have also tried using a ChannelFactory

```
            ws.AccountInfo ai = new ws.AccountInfo();
        ws.BasicAccountInfo[] info = new ws.BasicAccountInfo[10];

        ws.ProductAndService PaS = new ws.ProductAndService();

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        string address = "https://www.some-company.com:8443/DSMProgramsV4/PgnDSMProgramsService";
        WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;


        ChannelFactory<ws.PgnDSMProgramsService> factory = new ChannelFactory<ws.PgnDSMProgramsService>(binding, address);
        factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "Network Solutions DV Server CA");

        ws.PgnDSMProgramsService client = factory.CreateChannel();
        var infoz = client.GetAccountList("9999", "TEST", "999999");
```

Also no luck, same error message.

I have tried an assortment of web.config and app.config only like below to as simple as:

```
  <system.serviceModel>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CustomerEndpointBehavior" >
      <clientCredentials supportInteractive="True">
        <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="www.our-cert.org" />

       <!-- <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck"  />
          <sslCertificateAuthentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
        </serviceCertificate>-->
      </clientCredentials>

    </behavior>

  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<bindings>






  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="CustomerBindingConfig">
      <!--  closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="false"  allowCookies="false" > -->
      <!--     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" /> -->
      <security mode="Transport" >
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>

    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>


</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="https://www.some-company.com:8443/DSMProgramsV4/PgnDSMProgramsService"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomerBindingConfig" behaviorConfiguration="CustomerEndpointBehavior"
    contract="ws.PgnDSMProgramsService" name="serviceEndpoint" />
</client>
```

to a more complicated

```
  <system.serviceModel>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CustomerEndpointBehavior">

      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="www.our-cert.org" />
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>

    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CustomerBindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
          enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
            algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>


  </wsHttpBinding>


</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="https://www.some-company.com:8443/DSMProgramsV4/PgnDSMProgramsService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomerBindingConfig" behaviorConfiguration="CustomerEndpointBehavior" contract="ws.PgnDSMProgramsService" name="serviceEndpoint" />
</client>
```

Not like I have been doing my due diligence see below

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/7-simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011.aspx

http://robbincremers.me/2011/12/27/wcf-transport-security-and-client-certificate-authentication-with-self-signed-certificates/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18601/An-easy-way-to-use-certificates-for-WCF-security

http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/cfolini/archive/2008/01/04/90561.aspx

[Client certificates in wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403692/client-certificates-in-wcf)

https://notgartner.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/using-certificate-based-authentication-and-protection-with-windows-communication-foundation-wcf/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348595/Use-Mutual-SSL-Authentication-in-WCF

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45df57f0-e010-43ef-92f6-ed06c247d733/ssl-with-client-certificate

Comment: If you are doing client side certificate authentication you should not be sending them a SSL certificate (you said in your 'P.S.' that you send them a SSL cert without the private key), you should be sending them your client auth certificate.

Comment: we did send them our cert without the private key.  They told us we need to make a connection, using our certificate after we gave them our public key(as they requested without private key).  So when you say client auth certificate, me exporting my ssl cert key without a private key is not what they want?  how do i send them my "client auth certficate?  we already sent the the pfx file without the private key in it

Comment: A SSL certificate is not a client auth certificate. You will not be able to use a SSL certificate as a client auth certificate.

Comment: so i have to use a self signed certificate?  I cannot use a Certificate Authority like Networking Solutions?

this guy is using one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238936/wcf-ssl-certificate-using-an-enterprise-ca

Comment: You can use a public CA (such as VeriSign etc.) however you need to have a Client Authentication certificate issued to you, not a SSL certificate.

Comment: You could also use a self-signed certificate, however then you would need to provide your self-signed cert to the other party so they can add it to their trusted root certs store. If this an option with the third party it would probably be your best option.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, will get back to you on which ever works or they want to do!  Then just put all your comments together in an answer.  Will get back to you.

Comment: If you open up your certificate in your certificate store (using the certificate snap-in or through IE), you can verify that it is usable for client authentication. In the section that says 'This Certificate is intended for the following purpose(s)' you should have 'Proves your identity to a remote computer' as part of the listed uses. If it is, it can be used as a client cert, otherwise not.

Comment: It is checked off for Server Authentication and Client Authentication, and enabled.  

it looks like this in win8.1 and windows 2012 server  http://tinypic.com/r/6ghisn/8

in the cert itself it also says
Ensures the identity of a remote computer
Proves your identity to a remote computer

Comment: OK, then you should be able to use that certificate. Sorry about my earlier assertion, typically by 'SSL Certificate' is meant the 'server-to-client' authentication, looks like yours could be used for either.

Comment: well thanks for your help.  This has become a very frustrating ordeal.  The only thing I can do is try self signed or somebody can point out that I am doing something wrong.  Hopefully this will not end up a tumbleweed like most of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven’t already, you should enable WCF Tracing, which may help determine the root cause of WCF security issue. We have found that the WCF Trace log will reveal issues that were previously “hidden”.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it didnt seem to help me , maybe somebody?

http://pastebin.com/UwJuZR8q

www.some-site.com has been replaced fictitiously

Comment: inner exception: "System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream".  Any way to inquire about server side errors/issues?

Comment: thats what i was looking at as well. i forwarded on

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not an answer moderator might want to delete this question, still want to give credit to those that helped.   The server side(which i have no control over other then a phone call) had to use a different port 4443 instead of 8443 for TLS  (p.s allot of places have disabled SSL and that is marked as an answer to issues for my problem in allot of places)

Answer (score 1):

Since I am only the WCF client in this case, there is very little I can do. Obviously SoapUI can help prove it works. But if your developing in .NET and using WCF that doesnt help you. The customer is using a Layer7 middleware XML hardware appliance to also complicate matters. In the end i had to create a specific custom bining:

```
  <customBinding>
<binding name="Secured">
  <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"/>
  <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" requireClientCertificate="true"/>
</binding>
```

That seemed to "roll back" from Soap1.2

Also, the ip address I gave them was an issue. My website is in IIS and under a worker process that is binded to a web garden ip. Externally if you do a nslookup it comes out to 205.14.55.250 for example for my domain. But when added code to get my external ip address it was actually using another ip 205.14.55.251 (which is not assigned to any of the websites in my IIS)

Those two changes solved the problem